# similar transformation of rotation matrix by orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I am reading an old paper by Horn (see ch.4):
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372705?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

And for learning convenience of users, the following is a similar discussing:
[Finding the Similarity Transform of a rotation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46224/finding-the-similarity-transform-of-a-rotation-matrix)

Let $R$ be a rotation matrix.

Then there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$, such that $R = U^TAU$ with

[image]

So, for example, if $n=3$, then $A$ should look like
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0& 0 \\0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ 0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$$

How to prove this? (WLOG, suppose the size of matrices is odd.) In fact, $A$ is also an rotation matrix.

Comment: it is just the real version of the spectral theorem. Each $B_i$ corresponds to a complex conjugated pair eigenvalues of $R$.

Comment: @user251257 I see, thanks. The dimension of $B_i$ in such representation still makes me feel odd however.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @user251257 I mean I am not used to the eigenvalue $e^{\pm \theta} \in R$ corresponds to the eigenvalue $B_i\in R^{2\times 2}$

Comment: $B_i$ itself is a rotation, so it's eigenvalues have the form $\exp(\pm \mathbf i \beta)$ where $\mathbf i$ is the imaginary unit and $\beta\in [0,2\pi)$.